# syslog-ng crashes (SIGSEGV) on TLS

Tags: ssl, syslog-ng

OS: CentOS 7
syslog-ng version: 3.6.5

TLS is configured in /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf file.

```
key file is located in /etc/syslog-ng/key.d

cert file is located in /etc/syslog-ng/cert.d
```

It works fine if syslog-ng has been started from shell.

syslog-ng fails on TLS if it has been started via
service syslog-ng start.

With attached strace I can see that there is a permission problem.

```
access("/etc/syslog-ng/key.d/syslog-ng.key", R_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "Error opening TLS file; filename"..., 102) = 102
access("/etc/syslog-ng/cert.d/syslog-ng.cert", R_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "Error opening TLS file; filename"..., 104) = 104

drw-rw-rw-. 2 root root   26 Jan 10 10:44 key.d
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 5196 Jan 10 10:42 syslog-ng.key
```

I do simple TLS test with this command.

```
openssl s_client -connect <syslog-ng address>:6514
```

I've no clue why this is not working?
Can someone help on this?
Best regards
  Klaus

Comment: Hi, probably the script is running as a non-root user, and does not have access to the files/directories. Or some Apparmor/selinux rule is interfering with the script accessing these files.

Comment: Hi, thank you.
Yes SELinux was enabled that caused the problem.
I set it to disable now the files can be read.